# Extract elements from prop.tests in R

Tags: r

How can I extract elements from prop.tests in R?

```
summary(prop.test()) ### gives this

Length Class  Mode     
statistic   1      -none- numeric  
parameter   1      -none- numeric  
p.value     1      -none- numeric  
estimate    1      -none- numeric  
null.value  1      -none- numeric  
conf.int    2      -none- numeric  
alternative 1      -none- character
method      1      -none- character
data.name   1      -none- character
```

I want to extract the sample estimate and CIs.

Or is there a package that bring me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get hold of the estimates and CI directly:

```
smokers  <- c( 83, 90)
patients <- c( 86, 93)

result <- prop.test(smokers, patients)
result
```

which gives

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
    correction

data:  smokers out of patients
X-squared = 8.3539e-30, df = 1, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.05810303  0.05285172
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.9651163 0.9677419
```

Then you have that

```
result$estimate
result$conf.int
```

gives you

```
       prop 1    prop 2 
0.9651163 0.9677419 
>     result$conf.int
[1] -0.05810303  0.05285172
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```